# Filter rows of DataFrame by list of tuples

Tags: python, pandas

Let's assume I have the following DataFrame:

```
 dic = {'a' : [1, 1, 2, 2, 2, 2, 3, 3, 3, 3],
'b' : [1, 1, 1, 1, 2, 2, 1, 1, 2, 2],
'c' : ['f', 'f', 'f', 'e', 'f', 'f', 'f', 'e', 'f', 'f'],
'd' : [10, 20, 30, 40, 50, 60, 70, 80, 90, 100]}
df = pd.DataFrame(dic)

df
Out[10]: 
   a  b  c    d
0  1  1  f   10
1  1  1  f   20
2  2  1  f   30
3  2  1  e   40
4  2  2  f   50
5  2  2  f   60
6  3  1  f   70
7  3  1  e   80
8  3  2  f   90
9  3  2  f  100
```

In the following I want to take the values of column a and b, where c='e' and use those values to select respective rows of df (which would filter rows 2, 3, 6, 7). The idea is to create a list of tuples and index df by that list:

```
list_tup = list(df.loc[df['c'] == 'e', ['a','b']].to_records(index=False))
df_new = df.set_index(['a', 'b']).sort_index()

df_new
Out[13]: 
     c    d
a b        
1 1  f   10
  1  f   20
2 1  f   30
  1  e   40
  2  f   50
  2  f   60
3 1  f   70
  1  e   80
  2  f   90
  2  f  100

list_tup
Out[14]: [(2, 1), (3, 1)]

df.loc[list_tup]
```

Results in an TypeError: unhashable type: 'writeable void-scalar', which I don't understand. Any suggestions? I'm pretty new to python and pandas, hence I assume that I miss something fundamental.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I believe it's better to `groupby().transform()` and boolean indexing in this use case:

```
valids = (df['c'].eq('e')                # check if `c` is 'e`
            .groupby([df['a'],df['b']])  # group by `a` and `b`
            .transform('any')            # check if `True` occurs in the group
                                         # use the same label for all rows in group
         )

# filter with `boolean indexing
df[valids]
```

Output:

```
   a  b  c   d
2  2  1  f  30
3  2  1  e  40
6  3  1  f  70
7  3  1  e  80
```

---

A similar idea with `groupby().filter()` which is more readable but can be slightly slower:

```
df.groupby(['a','b']).filter(lambda x: x['c'].eq('e').any())
```

Comment: Thanks @QuangH , this worked for me :). Nevertheless I still don't see the bug in my previous approach. Could you explaint that?

Comment: @winj945 subtle differences between `numpy.int64` and `int64`. Use `tolist()` instead of `list` in `list_tup`, i.e. `list_tup = df.loc[...].to_records(...).tolist()`, and your code would work fine.

Answer (score 1):

You could try an innner join.

```
import pandas as pd
dic = {'a' : [1, 1, 2, 2, 2, 2, 3, 3, 3, 3],
'b' : [1, 1, 1, 1, 2, 2, 1, 1, 2, 2],
'c' : ['f', 'f', 'f', 'e', 'f', 'f', 'f', 'e', 'f', 'f'],
'd' : [10, 20, 30, 40, 50, 60, 70, 80, 90, 100]}
df = pd.DataFrame(dic)


df.merge(df.loc[df['c']=='e', ['a','b']], on=['a','b'])
```

Output

```
   a  b  c   d
0  2  1  f  30
1  2  1  e  40
2  3  1  f  70
3  3  1  e  80
```

Answer (score 1):

May be try a `MultiIndex`:

```
df_new.loc[pd.MultiIndex.from_tuples(list_tup)]
```

---

Full code:

```
list_tup = list(df.loc[df['c'] == 'e', ['a','b']].to_records(index=False))
df_new = df.set_index(['a', 'b']).sort_index()
df_new.loc[pd.MultiIndex.from_tuples(list_tup)]
```

---

Outputs:

```
     c   d
a b       
2 1  f  30
  1  e  40
3 1  f  70
  1  e  80
```

Answer (score 1):

Let us try

```
m = df[['a','b']].apply(tuple,1).isin(df.loc[df['c'] == 'e', ['a','b']].to_records(index=False).tolist())

out = df[m].copy()
```